# Calculating Divergence in COMSOL

Tags: pde, finite-element, comsol, automatic-differentiation

Is it computationally safe and accurate to use the following equation in COMSOL to compute the divergence of the vector quantity J (instead of using its general built-in equations that have $\nabla$ operations):

$$div_J = d(J_x,x)+d(J_y,y)+d(J_z,z)$$

Comment: It is ok as long as you derive the correct weak form (if the divergence term comes from a heat or momentum diffusion equation for instance). However, why would you want to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on so many simulations that I've run using my manual divergence calculation. The answer is yes. I also compared manual calculation with the built-in one and no error or different was observed.